# Green N White Screen issue in Camera activity Android

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, device

This bug is only on some devices.

*Project scope:*
Indoor navigation system used in malls/ships to locate shops.
It uses beacons to locate shops with bluetooth connection. It uses camera to show directions (arrow) image overlays.

In ArCameraActivity, half green screen shows up in camera preview.

code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity;

public class ARActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, ARView {


    private static boolean IS_NAVIGATION_CLICKED = false;

    @Inject
    ARPresenter presenter;

    @BindView(R.id.img_clear)
    ImageView imgClear;

    @BindView(R.id.img_logout)
    ImageView imgLogout;

    @BindView(R.id.img_map)
    ImageView imgMap;

    @BindView(R.id.img_navigation)
    ImageView imgNavigation;

    final static String TAG = "ARActivity";
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private FrameLayout cameraContainerLayout;
    private AROverlayView arOverlayView;
    private Camera camera;
    private ARCamera arCamera;
    private TextView tvCurrentLocation;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private final static int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 11;
    public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 0;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0;//1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public Location location;
    boolean isGPSEnabled;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled;
    boolean locationServiceAvailable;

    private ScanRegionsService scanRegionsService;

    private boolean isBeaconLoaded = false;

//    private static GetMallResponse.Data.Mall identifiedMall;

    private Dialog dialog = null;

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "http://98.156.231.92/maps/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ar);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        cameraContainerLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_container_layout);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        tvCurrentLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_current_location);
        arOverlayView = new AROverlayView(this);
        scanRegionsService = new ScanRegionsService(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                beginService();
            }
        }
        if (Util.getSelectedShop() != null) {
            showLoading();
        }
    }

    private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!isBeaconLoaded) {
                Log.d(TAG, "run: "+ isBeaconLoaded);
                dismissLoading();
                if(!isFinishing()) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(ARActivity.this)
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setTitle("There is no beacon in your surroundings")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to stop navigation?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            Util.setSelectedShop(null);
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    })

                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            if (permissions[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) &&
                    grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                beginService();
            } else if (permissions[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) &&
                    grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void beginService() {
        isBeaconLoaded = false;
        arOverlayView.registerReceiver();
        scanRegionsService.setupSpaces();
        scanRegionsService.startScanning();
        onMallIdentified(Util.getSelectedMall());
        new Handler().postDelayed(mRunnable, 10000);

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.img_map)
    public void onMapClicked() {
        arOverlayView.unregisterReceiver();
//        Util.getRouteMap().clear();
        Util.setSelectedShop(null);
//        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
//        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.img_navigation)
    public void onNavClicked() {
        if (!IS_NAVIGATION_CLICKED) {
            IS_NAVIGATION_CLICKED = true;
            arOverlayView.showNavigationMap();
            imgNavigation.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navigation_on));
        } else {
            IS_NAVIGATION_CLICKED = false;
            arOverlayView.hideNavigationMap();
            imgNavigation.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navigation_off));
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.img_logout)
    public void onLogoutClicked() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Confirm")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Util.set("authToken", "");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ARActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!((Activity) this).isFinishing()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Confirm")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the screen?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requestLocationPermission();
        requestCameraPermission();
        registerSensors();
        initAROverlayView();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ForegroundScanService.ACTION_DEVICE_DISCOVERED);
        registerReceiver(scanningBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    public void showClearMap() {
        imgClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideClearMap() {
        imgClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.img_clear)
    public void onClearClicked() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Confirm")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to stop navigation?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Util.setSelectedShop(null);
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(scanningBroadcastReceiver);
        releaseCamera();
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void requestCameraPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        } else {
            initARCameraView();
        }
    }

    public void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        } else {
            initLocationService();
        }
    }

    public void initAROverlayView() {
        if (arOverlayView.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) arOverlayView.getParent()).removeView(arOverlayView);
        }
        cameraContainerLayout.addView(arOverlayView);
    }

    public void initARCameraView() {
        reloadSurfaceView();

        if (arCamera == null) {
            arCamera = new ARCamera(this, surfaceView);
        }
        if (arCamera.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) arCamera.getParent()).removeView(arCamera);
        }
        cameraContainerLayout.addView(arCamera);
        arCamera.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        initCamera();
    }

    private void initCamera() {
        int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if (numCams > 0) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                camera.startPreview();
                arCamera.setCamera(camera);
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void reloadSurfaceView() {
        if (surfaceView.getParent() != null) {
            ((ViewGroup) surfaceView.getParent()).removeView(surfaceView);
        }

        cameraContainerLayout.addView(surfaceView);
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();
            arCamera.setCamera(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    private void registerSensors() {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            float[] rotationMatrixFromVector = new float[16];
            float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
            float[] rotatedProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrixFromVector, sensorEvent.values);

            if (arCamera != null) {
                projectionMatrix = arCamera.getProjectionMatrix();
            }

            Matrix.multiplyMM(rotatedProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, rotationMatrixFromVector, 0);
            this.arOverlayView.updateRotatedProjectionMatrix(rotatedProjectionMatrix);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
        //do nothing
    }

    private void initLocationService() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            this.locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(this.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Get GPS and network status
            this.isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            this.isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isNetworkEnabled && !isGPSEnabled) {
                // cannot get location
                this.locationServiceAvailable = false;
            }

            this.locationServiceAvailable = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    updateLatestLocation();
                }
            }

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    updateLatestLocation();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());

        }
    }

    private void updateLatestLocation() {
        if (arOverlayView != null && location != null) {
            arOverlayView.updateCurrentLocation(location);
            tvCurrentLocation.setText(String.format("lat: %s \nlon: %s \naltitude: %s \n",
                    location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateLatestLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver scanningBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ");
            isBeaconLoaded = true;
            String shopname=Util.getSelectedShop().getShopImage();
            Toast.makeText(context, "You are in "+shopname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int devicesCount = intent.getIntExtra(BackgroundScanService.EXTRA_DEVICES_COUNT, 0);
            RemoteBluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BackgroundScanService.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.i("BEACON", String.format("Total discovered devices: %d\n\nLast scanned device:\n%s", devicesCount, device.toString()));
//            statusText.setText(String.format("Total discovered devices: %d\n\nLast scanned device:\n%s", devicesCount, device.toString()));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onMallIdentified(GetMallResponse.Data.Mall mall) {
//        identifiedMall = mall;
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Identified "+mall.getPropertyName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        presenter.loadShops(mall.getId());
        presenter.loadRouteBeacons(mall.getId());
    }

    public void onUnkownPlaceIdentified() {
        arOverlayView.registerReceiver();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unknown place identified", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        List<GetRouteBeaconsResponse.Data.Route> floorRoute = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShopLoaded(List<GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop> shops) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onShopLoaded");
        if (shops.size() > 0) {
            Util.shopMap.clear();
            Log.i(TAG, "onShopLoaded shops.size " + shops.size());
            Util.activeDeviceMap.clear();
            for (GetShopsResponse.Data.Shop shop : shops) {
                Util.shopMap.put("" + shop.getId(), shop);
                if (shop.getAdImage().length() > 0) {
                    Drawable drbl = Util.promoImageMap.get(IMAGE_URL + shop.getAdImage());
                    if (drbl == null) {
                        String imgkey = IMAGE_URL + shop.getAdImage();
                        drbl = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.promo1, null);
                        Util.promoImageMap.put(imgkey, drbl);
                        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Drawable drb2 = drawableFromUrl(imgkey);
                                    Util.promoImageMap.put(IMAGE_URL + shop.getAdImage(), drb2);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Unable to download image");
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        new Thread(runnable).start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteBeaconLoaded(List<GetRouteBeaconsResponse.Data.Route> floors) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteBeaconLoaded: ");
        Log.i(TAG, "onRouteBeaconLoaded");
//        if (floors.size()>0 && Util.getSelectedShop()!=null){
//            Log.i(TAG, "onRouteBeaconLoaded floors.size "+floors.size());
//            Util.getRouteMap().clear();
//            for (GetRouteBeaconsResponse.Data.Route route: floors){
//                String comkey = route.proximityUUID+route.major+route.minor;
//                Util.getRouteMap().put(comkey, route);
//            }
//            Util.setSelectedShop(Util.getSelectedShop());
//            Log.i(TAG, "onShopLoaded setup space scanRegionsService");
//            scanRegionsService.setupSpaces();
//            Log.i(TAG, "onShopLoaded startScanning");
//            scanRegionsService.startScanning();
//        }
        if (floors.size() > 0) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onRouteBeaconLoaded floors.size " + floors.size());
            Util.getRouteMap().clear();
            for (GetRouteBeaconsResponse.Data.Route route : floors) {
                String comkey = route.proximityUUID + route.major + route.minor;
                Util.getRouteMap().put(comkey, route);
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "onShopLoaded setup space scanRegionsService");
            scanRegionsService.setupSpaces();
            Log.i(TAG, "onShopLoaded startScanning");
            scanRegionsService.startScanning();

        }

        arOverlayView.registerReceiver();
    }

    public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        Bitmap x;
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return new BitmapDrawable(x);
    }

    private void initLoadingDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.show_loading);
        TextView txtFind = dialog.findViewById(R.id.findingBeacons);
        txtFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                                 KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }

    public void showLoading() {
        try {
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                initLoadingDialog();
                dialog.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void dismissLoading() {
        try {
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

[green screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApPnj.jpg)
Getting like this for camera activity in redmi y2 phone only. Its works well on other models. What might be issue? It shows directions in camera to shop using beacon device. Android os version is not problem.

white screen on some devices - samsung tab, oneplus 7, BLU G9 Pro phone
[white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpYBf.png)

> this activity shows navigation with help of beacons in camera shows overlay of imageview. it works on some devices, i have tried various methods to resolve it,
> doesn't work. added latest camera v2 api.

---

How can i resolve this issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: some suggestion I have got: try using camera api instead camera v2, set hardware accelration true in manifest, use camera app for taking images.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this "green screen" issue is caused by the camera's preview resolution. Try to get supported preview size from camera instance.

```
mParams = mCamera.getParameters();

List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes = mParams.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

Camera.Size bestPreviewSize = supportedPreviewSizes.get(0);

for (Camera.Size sz : supportedPreviewSizes) {
    /* perfect match */
    if(sz.width == mWidth && sz.height == mHeight) {
        bestPreviewSize = sz;
        break;
    } else {
        int bestArea = bestPreviewSize.width*bestPreviewSize.height;
        int currArea = sz.width*sz.height;
        int targetArea = mWidth*mHeight;

        if (Math.abs(currArea-targetArea) < Math.abs(bestArea-targetArea)) {
            bestPreviewSize = sz;
        }
    }
}

mCurrWidth = bestPreviewSize.width;
mCurrHeight = bestPreviewSize.height;

mParams.setPreviewSize(mCurrWidth, mCurrHeight);

/* Set preview format */
mParams.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

/* Apply Parameters */
mCamera.setParameters(mParams);

mCamera.startPreview();
```

You can also try to force some fixed resolution depending on some device conditions, like display width, for example. Some resolutions i found useful on my use case:

```
width = 1280;
heigth = 720;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    WindowMetrics windowMetrics = getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();

    if (isPortrait) {
        if (windowMetrics.getBounds().width() <= 720) {
            width = 720;
            heigth = 480;
        }
    } else {
        if (windowMetrics.getBounds().width() <= 1344) {
            width = 960;
            heigth = 540;
        }
    }
} else {
    if (isPortrait) {
        if (getDisplay().getWidth() <= 720) {
            width = 720;
            heigth = 480;
        }
    } else {
        if (getDisplay().getWidth() <= 1344) {
            width = 960;
            heigth = 540;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the best solution for me was getting the supported sizes to calculate the best preview size.